# "Identify-this" tagged questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, identify

I've seen this many times. Most of the questions tagged with `identify-this-movie` or `identify-this-'something'` are not received well. Most of the time those questions were asked by new members and even the question was asked by old, experienced user, that type of questions would not receive proper attention and/or good appreciation from community here.

Those questions often doesn't include proper format or enough information or question just included a few things about what he/she remembers.

Those type of questions shows a great challenge to give a answer and was not very well received most of the times.

Should we need some kind of different standard for questions tagged with `identify-this-"something"`?

Should there be specific guidelines for those questions?

Comment: Didn't we discussed that 100 times already ;D

Comment: yeah, but final result is still the same nah? Im just saying, it could be better if something changed for these

Comment: @Vishwa There are specific guidelines on the [on-topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: We have no way of requiring or enforcing anything in the way of quality... we can't stop users from writing half-assed questions. All we can do is close the bad ones until the OP fixes them, if ever. What do you want us to do?

Answer (score 5):

Most ID questions **do NOT** have the level of detail we ask for.... about 2/3 that DON'T.

Let's look at the guidance...

- Plot details of any scenes you remember
- Descriptions of any characters or locations
- Where you watched the movie or TV show
- When you watched the movie or TV show
- Any idea of how old it was
- Any idea of country of origin (if known)
- Whether it was animated or not
- Any other distinctive detail

REALLY?

**Anyone** should be able to answer 6 or 7 of those points.

We're "strict" when users **don't bother** to even address the points there. They just dash off their question, scurry away and then rarely come back to "contribute" further to the site.

Comment: Yes, but there are also the moderators who vote to close a question with a comment like 'does not meet our standards for quality' when the question had plenty of this information.  There's a bias towards very wordy questions, when sometimes brevity and precision count.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the rules of identify-this policy are to strict. I mean sometimes the asker would gladly provide more detail to his/her question but he/her simply doesn't have it. I know (from personal example) that sometimes you can only remember just one or two scenes from the movie and thats it. No actors, years and countries of release etc., just one scene that got engraved in your memory. I think that those people should aslo have an equal chance to find their movies just as the others who have a better memory.
[This answer might also help.](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2863/53395)

Comment: There are no "Rules" just users opinions and, more often than not, with a little prompting, a user CAN recall more information. That's what "ON HOLD" is for...it's not the end of everything, it provides the asker an opportunity to **improve** the question and have the "hold" reversed. Please do not take one Q&A in isolation as validation of your position. It's possible, in hindsight, that I was wrong to answer the question at all.

Comment: By "rules" i meant [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also I have a couple more movies I really can't recall more information because of few reasons: 1. I was very young when I watched it,it was a long, long time ago, 2. I cought those few scenes on TV and then maybe switched the chanel or something, 3. Those scenes were probably from the end or near the end of the movie, I have nothing else. @Paulie_D

Comment: Yeah, but year/language/channel/ actor descriptions...those you *should* know.  **We don't know how old you are**..so a "long time ago" or "young age"** mean nothing to us. Take some time to think about ALL the detail you remember BEFORE asking. Don't just post what you remember and expect us to prompt you for more infrmation. Use the points listed in the on-topic guidance as bullet points that you MUST answer, even if you can only approximate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice I'll think about it more next time, but can I ask you what should I do if I really can't remember some of those MUST information? @Paulie_D

Comment: Approximate.....or say that you can't recall. At least then we know that you have thought about it. But in my experience you **can** recall those basic points if you try.

Comment: Ok, I might have rushed it a little bit, I'll keep this in mind for the future, thanks man @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D, approximate year you saw it and language: sure. Channel: not necessarily, especially if you didn't choose it. Actor descriptions: seriously?? That's fine if you have a good visual memory, but I couldn't give you actor descriptions for something I watched yesterday.