# Identify-This-X question put on hold

Tags: discussion, identify

I recently asked [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83818/identifying-a-couple-serial-killer-movie-involving-kids) a few days ago, asking for some help identifying this movie, for which I had a very vague memory. That scene I felt was unique enough for it to be identified, and even did about 15 minutes of google searching for it before I asked the question.

Things like "body bag", serial killers, etc. I couldn't find it anywhere. I actually think at one point, I may have come across "running scared" (The identified movie), but eliminated it because I didn't know the full plot, and my scene didn't fit the overall plot.

I provided what I knew, although, I missed a few details about the time period, but edited them in after the first comment. I understand the first downvote, but I noticed over the course of a few hours I was met with several more downvotes (And eventually the question was closed).

The provided information was clearly enough to identify the movie: A user provided the exact movie, and even a link to the exact scene I was talking about.

I have a bad memory, (something that I'm frankly afraid to admit at times), and I feel like I was penalized for this (Not because the question was bad). I tried to follow the first comment's suggestions, and edited my post, but was still met with downvotes. Also, this comment struck me as well:

> Did you happen to ask this question b4? I answered twice b4 (months ago) and both questions were closed and deleted.

If these questions were asked/answered months ago, and were closed/deleted, it would not have come across in my searching. I could have avoided asking this question at all. I feel like if these questions are unique enough to be answered (And have correctly upvoted/checked answers), it **SHOULD NOT** be closed and/or deleted, as the question itself was enough to identify the movie in question. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Its not your fault ... the site has a long a tortuous history with ID questions.  They are not loved by many people on the site.  Indeed we are currently going through some introspection about their future on the site.  See:  https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/check-in-on-identification-questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my “Identify-this” question put on hold for lacking information (off topic - Identification)?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2860/49) and [Why `identify-this-movie` questions are always downvoted even if perfectly valid?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1908/49)

Comment: Whether the movie is successfully identified based on the question does not have any bearing on whether the question meets the community standards for ID questions. Carefully read the help center. Strange to say but if you use the fact that you now know what movie it is to edit your question and bring it up to the standards in the help center, it can be reopened. Also a downvote is **not** a “penalty” for you. It’s just a value placed on the content with respect to the goal of the site. It’s not personal. If you participate, you will get downvotes sometimes. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I should not need to edit my question afterwards with more information about how do identify a movie, with information I didn't know at the time. My question was answered...I provided enough information for it to be specifically identified, correct grammar, and added additional information that paulie asked me to add. The question should have never been closed. And to say a downvote is **not** a penalty, is simply wrong. If privileges are gained through the rep system, and I lose a privilege, how can you consider that not a penalty?

Comment: Take it however you want to. I can’t speak to what you should or shouldn’t need to do. I’m just pointing out things about how SE works. Note that if you posted an answer that got 1000 down votes and 1000 up votes, you would end up with a rep gain of 8,000 after all is said and done. It’s just a number on a web site. There will always always always be some people who don’t like what you’ve written. Either accept it or be frequently annoyed. Another way to look at this is that you got your answer, so why does it matter whether the question is on hold?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Because this question will eventually get deleted, and future users will not be able to gain the benefit of madmada's answer.

Comment: Well if you want to serve the community, then the way forward is to edit the question. The only other option is to try to get the rules changed but based on another thread about ID questions, that’s very unlikely to happen.

Comment: @ToddWilcox This is ideally what this meta question was supposed to address.

Comment: Problem is, these rules grew over years of having to deal with this issue and wade through tons and tons of low quality and low value questions each and every day. We *had* no rules, it brought us exactly where we are now.